# Create two (slightly) different executables from same visual c# project

Tags: c#, msbuild, build

I have a visual c# project from which I want to compile two executables: Full.exe, and Limited.exe.  Limited.exe simply hides a couple of UI controls.

I'm thinking of adding another pair of solution configuration (DebugLimited and ReleaseLimited) which simply sets a flag, and then in my build script just build my app with Release configuration and with ReleaseLimited configuration.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want 2 differnet executables this approach works. Make sure that each flavor builds into its own directory. "Build-> batch build" option will let you build all of them at once.

If goal is to have different UI instead of different executables you can use setting in .config file to control what UI to show/hide (with appropritate code to turn on/off controls).

Answer (score 0):

I would make a couple of projects.  One called Full and the other called Limited.  They are simply wrappers around your main project and set your appropriate options before starting.  This way, on a full build of your solution you always get both executables.

Comment: How do I build just a wrapper around a project?  My project is medium size - about 15 windows, some other controls, image files, etc.

Comment: @Martin: I should think that you make your project into a library and your executable projects reference the library.

Comment: What would be the advantage vs have an extra set of configurations, in addition to Build All building both apps?

Comment: @Martin:  I'm assuming that building using configurations only builds one executable at a time and that my answer allows you to build both when building the solution.